# Failed to compile. ./src/LineGraph.js Module not found: Recursion in resolving

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I installed successfully `react-chartjs-2` and `chart.js` via `npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js` but when I tried using `LinkGraph` I got the error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/LineGraph.js
Module not found: Recursion in resolving
```

Please help.

Comment: `npm i chart.js` do it separately

Comment: Run `node -v` and `npm -v` to check version of `node.js` and `npm` and copy them here.

Comment: Add  your package.json also with the question :) Would like to see that !

Comment: node version = v14.13.0

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save chart.js` do it separately

Apparently, even though it's referred on package.json you have to install it individually

for more info see this discussion on react-chartjs-2 [issue](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/134#issuecomment-466063602)

Comment: Hello Roy.B,  npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js is already installed by doing this. The answer doesn't make sense friend :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather this is the solution [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/134#issuecomment-466063602) recommended

Comment: I checked the pacakge docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2 , they don't mention any such thing friend :) They instead recommend npm install --save react-chartjs-2 chart.js

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather you don't need to check, just click on the link I added